# Java RegEx for email domain

Tags: java, android, regex, string, email

I try to restrict the email option in my registration form (Android app) to my university's domain only (i.e. `***********@aou.edu.sa` or `***********@arabou.edu.sa`).

The code I've got so far is this:

```
public void validateEmail(EditText anEmail){

    //String regex declaration for student emails
    String emailPatS = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@" + "[aou.edu.sa]";

    //string regex declaration for tutor emails
    String emailPatT = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@" + "[arabou.edu.sa]";

    //Pattern declaration for student and tutor emails
    Pattern studentPat = Pattern.compile(emailPatS);
    Pattern tutorPat = Pattern.compile(emailPatT);

    //Matcher declaration for student and tutor emails
    Matcher studentMatch = studentPat.matcher(anEmail.getText().toString());
    Matcher tutorMatch = tutorPat.matcher(anEmail.getText().toString());

    //if else for email editText validation
    if(studentMatch.matches()){
        submitForm();
    } else {
        //if it doesn't match, first don't allow the user to click sign up button
        //then compare to see if it's a tutor's email
        signUp.setEnabled(false);
        if(tutorMatch.matches()){ //if it does match a tutor's email then allow the user to click sign up and submit the form
            signUp.setEnabled(true);
            submitForm();
        } else { //if it matches neither student nor tutor emails then disallow user to
            //click sign up and toast an error message
            signUp.setEnabled(false);
            anEmail.setError("Please enter your university email only.");
            if(regEmail.isInEditMode()){
                signUp.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But every time I try to run the app it crashes at the register activity, due to this particular piece of code.

Any ideas of an alternative and easier way?

Comment: **CRASH** then add error logcat...

Comment: I am not sure if your reqex is correct `String emailPatS = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@" + "[aou.edu.sa]";` Have you seen any email id starting with a number

Comment: I just tried it again. It's not crashing anymore but the email regex doesn't fit the pattern and it doesn't trigger an error.

Comment: @YatiSawhney Actually I haven't. Thanks for pointing that out =)

Comment: There is no perfect e-mail regex.

Comment: you could use one regex for both student and tutor sign up using `^[_A-Za-z0-9-+]+(?:\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@(?:aou\.edu\.sa|arabou\.edu\.sa)$` . See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/d57hIA/1). As @lexicore pointed out, there is no perfect e-mail regex. this regex is just based on what you already had in the question.

Comment: public void validateEmail(EditText anEmail){ String email = anEmail.getText().toString(); boolean endsWithDomain = email.endsWith("aou.edu.sa"); if(endsWithDomain && Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) { // do what you want to do } else { Log.d("App","Email not verified");} }

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. They helped greatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the following regex a try and see the demo [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/JHHTUt/1) as well:

```
^([_A-Za-z0-9-+]+\.?[_A-Za-z0-9-+]+@(aou.edu.sa|arabou.edu.sa))$
```

The problem was in catching the domain of the email - the part after `@`. You used `[]` brackets which define a group dis/allowed characters (depends on the `^`) usage. In case you have just a little number of possibilities, you can simply define them between `()` brackets and separate with `|` (`or`) character.

```
(aou.edu.sa|arabou.edu.sa)
```

In the regex, I have introduced above, it recognizes an email just with one dot `.` (as far as I have read from your attempt). You can make a simple change to allow more of the dots.

Edit: Don't forget in Java to escape the dot character with a double slash `\\` of course.